# List returned from Series.axes doesn't look like a normal list

Tags: python, list, pandas, numpy

From the pandas documentation, i get `Series.axes` will return a list, and indeed it is a list

```
$ python3 process_data.py 
<class 'list'>
```

However, when I attempted to print the string representation of the list, I get this

To run print directly

```
print(row.axes)


$ python3 process_data.py 
Index(['rank', 'name','high', 'low', 'analysis'],
      dtype='object')
```

Which doesn't look like a normal list at all.

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I still can access the information in the weird list by doing `list_name[0][index]`, which is like a two-dimensional list. I mean if its internal type is list, how can it have this behavior. If it is a numpy array like object, why the internal type is still list.

EDIT:

```
def process_nextfile(date, catagory):
    df1 = pd.read_csv('{}all_csv/{}/catagory{}'.format(BASE_DIR, date, catagory), header = None, names = CATAGORY_HEADER[catagory-1])
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        print(row.axes.__name__)
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_nextfile('2016-04-05', 2)
```

Comment: I don't use pandas, but have you tried `row.axes. __name__`?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 `'list' object has no attribute '__name__'
`

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: @MYGz The full code is added. The csv is just a normal csv file. Nothing fancy

Comment: Oops, I meant `type(variable).__name__`.

Comment: @Bobby It gives a list of pandas series objects. What is your requirement? You can do `row.tolist()` while iterating over `df.iterrows()` to convert to list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `iterrows()`, every row is a pandas Series, the `axes` attribute returns a list of labels/or index. So what is contained in the list are index objects, check this simple example:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
s.axes
# [RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)]
```

To get a normal list, you can access the index object and then convert it to a list:

```
s.axes[0].tolist()
# [0, 1, 2]
```